# Complete (not heurestic) proof of Ito lemma?

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Where can I find a formal and complete proof of Ito lemma. I found a few of them but all are "heurestic" type like on Wikipedia, operating on $dX_t$ notation. Not really proofs. Thank you for any links.

Comment: hmmm...any lecture notes on stochastic differential equations?

Comment: Most books on this topic (stochastic integrals/stochastic analysis/SDEs) contain a proof of this statement. I like the book by René Schilling & Lothar Partzsch ("Brownian motion - An Introduction to Stochastic Processes") pretty much; in particular they give a (detailed) proof of Itô's formula for Brownian motion as well as for Itô processes.